# Input makes tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory() not work on PyCharm

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

I've previously asked a question about why `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()` doesn't work for me a second time in a program (it looks like the computer flickers for a second but the folder-choosing window doesn't pop-up and the program is awaiting input), but no one has been able to replicate my issue.

However, I have now discovered that it doesn't work only if before I call that function I have some kind of regular `input()` (I can call it as many times as I want as long as the program doesn't have any input before). It's weird because if I run my py file on CMD it works as intended. Are there any suggestions as to how to fix it?

My PyCharm version is the newest. I am on Windows 10 and using Python 3.8, and it worked for my friend who has Windows 10 and Python 3.6 (so it's clearly not a problem with my python version).

Also, for clarification, I have used the usual

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

before calling the above function.

Comment: `input()` requires a console or terminal to work.  Better not use `input()` in a GUI application, use `simpledialog.askstring()`.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. I actually plan on moving everything to GUI (the file choosing is the first thing which isn't in the console in my program), but at the moment this looks like a good solution. Do you know what could be wrong though? I don't think `input()` should make something unrelated not work.